# Creating directory page from single source for multiple sub directories (Doxygen)

Tags: doxygen

For my doxygen project, I have setup the program such that every directory in a large, multilevel project is doxygenized while linking itself to its subdirectories by way of tagfiles.

Because the files tab does not account for this nested tagging method, I decided to use an external File Tree plugin for jquery that dynamically loads the subdirectory tree dynamically via PHP. I have the code setup in external/directories.txt with standard page comments so that every subdirectory doxygen uses the same external folder as an input.

However, when I attempt to create a page called Directory with the name of directory.html, it no longer generates the page after a few doxygen runs through subdirectories. When I changed the name to directory_tree, it begins to generate again for some time until it exhausts most subdirectories. Is there any way to have pages with the same name on a per directory basis even when tagfiles are used? Thanks.

Edit: My original post is extremely confusing, so I'm clarifying it here.

I have a generic file called directories.txt in a folder called input that looks like this:

```
/**
@page directory Directories
<h2>Click on text to go to directory, Click on tab to see subdirectories</h2> 
<div id="fileTree" class="demo"></div>
*/
```

The idea is that every time i run doxygen on a directory, I would pull from this generic file to create a page called directories since the fileTree is a generic template to create a directory map for all subdirectories underneath the directory. However, because doxygen does not allow for the same named pages for linked projects via tagfiles, I can't generate a file called directory.html for every directory automatically. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Can you show a bit more clear what you want?

Comment: Did you have a look at commands like `\includedoc` and `\snippetdoc`?

Comment: Since I am documenting company's code, I would need to achieve what I want by editing the configuration file in some way rather than the comment blocks themselves. So I most likely cannot use includedoc and snippetdoc.

Comment: Can you create a small example of the code you have and the problems you encounter (including the changes in the Doxyfile compared to the standard settings).

Comment: What I want is to have a file named directory.html in every single doxygen directory such that in the tree a/b/c where a, b, and c all contain doxygen files such that there exists a/directory.html, b/directory.html, c/directory.html where b is connected to c using c's tagfile and a is connected to b+c using b's and c's tagfiles.

Comment: I think I get a bit the grasp of it, the basic problem is in the tag files and the results that are displayed in doxygen. Best is to concentrate on how is it possible to fix this / what is the exact problem here (I recently checked some problems with tag files and they were already solved in the current version). Important question, which version of doxygen are you using?, when not 1.8.14 try to upgrade to 1.8.14 or even better try to build from the doxygen repository.

Comment: I am currently on version 1.8.11.

Comment: Please try 1.8.14 or newer and report back.

Comment: I’m getting the following error on 1.8.15: directory:-1 warning: multiple use of section label ‘directory’, (first occurence: directory)

Comment: Please show the code, makes it so much easier to discuss / see where a problem / solution is.

Comment: /**
@page directory Directories
<h2>Click on text to go to directory, Click on tab to see subdirectories</h2> 
<div id="fileTree" class="demo"></div>
*/